# Mysql result show in php loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to get the result from "headline" and "content" to show up one at a time and then fade in and out to the next result in a loop. Currently, it shows all the results at once and the fades in and out and then show all the results again. Any idea on how to get them to show one at a time TIA

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #table1{/*table aspects and design */
        border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        display:none;
        width: 60%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    th{/*align table headers*/
        text-align:center;
    }
    td,th{
        border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>

 <table id="table1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%">
    <? if ($query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Announcements_Current`"))
     {
/* select all information from the table and take it into the page  */
    $query->execute(); 
    while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $head = $result['headline'];/*puts result of headline from table into variable*/
        $content = $result['content'];
        /*puts result of content from  table into variable*/
        echo /* echo the table to display announcements*/'
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h1>
                    '.$head.'
                </h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font size="4">
                '.$content.'
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>';

 }
}
?>
</table> <!--end of table-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* define script for jquery*/
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {/* for loop to fade in and out the announcements*/

$(document).ready(function() {/*function to fade table in and out*/
$('#table1').fadeIn(2000);
$('#table1').delay(5000);
$('#table1').fadeOut(2000);
}  
)};
</script>
```

Comment: for this one you should use ajax. it wont work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a timer in your Javascript to show each row separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cur_row = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#table1 tr").fadeOut(2000).eq(cur_row).fadeIn(2000);
        cur_row = (cur_row + 1) % $("table1 tr").length;
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried doing this but am just getting a blank screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the table rows in Developer Tools?

Comment: The rows are not appearing in the Developer tools

Comment: But you see the `<table>`, and it's empty? Then your query is not returning any rows.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working. Thank you so much for your help!!